# How to add a new column AND insert rows conditionally (in the same script)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to add column to a table. If that part of my script executes, I also want to add some values to the table. How can I do it  ?

```
  if not exists (select 1 from sys.columns 
                 where object_id = object_id('CAT_MASSUPDATETASKPARAM') 
                 and name = 'ValueBoolean' )
  begin
           alter table CAT_MASSUPDATETASKPARAM add ValueBoolean bit NULL 
  end
  go

  IF (the first script was running do this script )
       INSERT INTO CAT_MASSUPDATETASKPARAM ( ParentTaskIK,    
              ParamType,ParamName,ValueInt,ValueStr,ValueBoolean)
       SELECT ParentTaskIK, 'Boolean','SHOW_CURRENT',NULL,NULL,1
       FROM   CAT_MASSUPDATETASKPARAM ,CAT_MASSUPDATETASK
       WHERE  CAT_MASSUPDATETASKPARAM.ParentTaskIK = CAT_MASSUPDATETASK.Id
       AND    CAT_MASSUPDATETASK.MassUpdateType in ('somthing','somthing1')
       GROUP BY ParentTaskIK  
 go
```

Comment: Your title is pretty ambiguous..... can you be more descriptive in the body but specific in the question title? :)

Comment: Have you accidentally some word? :)

Comment: fyi, modified content to clarify the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the 2nd part to run only if the column was added in the first... Put it in the same begin-end block.  But you need dynamic SQL because the column existence is checked at compile time.

```
if not exists (select 1 from sys.columns where object_id =     object_id('CAT_MASSUPDATETASKPARAM') and name = 'ValueBoolean')
begin
    alter table CAT_MASSUPDATETASKPARAM  add ValueBoolean bit NULL;
    EXEC ('
    INSERT INTO CAT_MASSUPDATETASKPARAM ( ParentTaskIK,    ParamType,ParamName,ValueInt,ValueStr,ValueBoolean)
        select ParentTaskIK, ''Boolean'',''SHOW_CURRENT'',NULL,NULL,1
        from CAT_MASSUPDATETASKPARAM ,CAT_MASSUPDATETASK
        where CAT_MASSUPDATETASKPARAM.ParentTaskIK = CAT_MASSUPDATETASK.Id
        and CAT_MASSUPDATETASK.MassUpdateType in (''somthing'',''somthing1'')
        group by ParentTaskIK     ');
end
go
```

Otherwise within the same session, you can use a temp table or some such marker:

```
if not exists (select 1 from sys.columns where object_id =     object_id('CAT_MASSUPDATETASKPARAM') and name = 'ValueBoolean')
begin
    alter table CAT_MASSUPDATETASKPARAM  add ValueBoolean bit NULL;
    create table #marker (id int);
end;
GO
if object_id('tempdb..#marker') is not null
    INSERT INTO CAT_MASSUPDATETASKPARAM (
        ParentTaskIK,ParamType,ParamName,ValueInt,ValueStr,ValueBoolean)
    select ParentTaskIK, 'Boolean','SHOW_CURRENT',NULL,NULL,1
        from CAT_MASSUPDATETASKPARAM ,CAT_MASSUPDATETASK
        where CAT_MASSUPDATETASKPARAM.ParentTaskIK = CAT_MASSUPDATETASK.Id
        and CAT_MASSUPDATETASK.MassUpdateType in ('somthing','somthing1')
        group by ParentTaskIK;
```

Comment: 10x
@RichardTheKiwi 
I used the first anwser